# How can I automate the "generate scripts" task in SQL Server Management Studio 2008?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2008, automation, ssms, sql-server-2008

I'd like to automate the script generation in SQL Server Management Studio 2008.

Right now what I do is :

- Right click on my database, Tasks, "Generate Scripts..."
- manually select all the export options I need, and hit select all on the "select object" tab
- Select the export folder
- Eventually hit the "Finish" button

Is there a way to automate this task?

Edit : I want to generate **creation** scripts, not change scripts.

Comment: did you found the answer? I want to do this too, I used Publishing, it saved on hard, don't know where and there I don't have all options that are when generating a script :-?

Comment: As mentioned in several of the answers,Use SMO if you are a developer

Answer (score 32, accepted):

What Brann is mentioning from the Visual Studio 2008 SP1 Team Suite is version 1.4 of the Database Publishing Wizard. It's installed with sql server 2008 (maybe only professional?) to \Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\Publishing\1.4. The VS call from server explorer is simply calling this. You can achieve the same functionality via the command line like:

```
sqlpubwiz help script
```

I don't know if v1.4 has the same troubles that v1.1 did (users are converted to roles, constraints are not created in the right order), but it is not a solution for me because it doesn't script objects to different files like the Tasks->Generate Scripts option in SSMS does. I'm currently using a modified version of Scriptio (uses the MS SMO API) to act as an improved replacement for the database publishing wizard (sqlpubwiz.exe). It's not currently scriptable from the command line, I might add that contribution in the future.

Scriptio was originally posted on Bill Graziano's blog, but has subsequently been released to CodePlex by Bill and updated by others. Read the discussion to see how to compile for use with SQL Server 2008.

http://scriptio.codeplex.com/

EDIT: I've since started using RedGate's SQL Compare product to do this. It's a very nice replacement for all that sql publishing wizard should have been. You choose a database, backup, or snapshot as the source, and a folder as the output location and it dumps everything nicely into a folder structure. It happens to be the same format that their other product, SQL Source Control, uses.

Comment: Is there an equivalent in 2012? I'd just be happy if the wizard remembered my settings like "Script Indexes".

Comment: @PeterX SMSS > Tools > Options > SQL Server Object Explorer > Scripting

Comment: For 2012 follow this guide: https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/automated-script-generation-with-powershell-and-smo/

Comment: @zanlok very useful comment.  Unfortunately they are missing the "Include unsupported statements" option in SQL Server 2014.

Comment: I have forked the scriptio codeplex repository to GitHub https://github.com/fredatgithub/Scriptio

Answer (score 53):

SqlPubwiz has very limited options compared to the script generation in SSMS. By contrast the options available with [SMO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms220218) almost exactly match those in SSMS, suggesting it is probably even the same code. (I would hope MS didn't write it twice!) There are several examples on MSDN like [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162153) that show scripting tables as individual objects. However if you want everything to script correctly with a 'full' schema that includes 'DRI' (Declarative Referential Integrity) objects like foreign keys then scripting tables individually doesn't work the dependencies out correctly. I found it is neccessary to collect all the URNs and hand them to the scripter as an array. This code, modified from the example, works for me (though I daresay you could tidy it up and comment it a bit more):

```cs
    using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo;
    using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc;
    // etc...

    // Connect to the local, default instance of SQL Server. 
    Server srv = new Server();

    // Reference the database.  
    Database db = srv.Databases["YOURDBHERE"];

    Scripter scrp = new Scripter(srv);
    scrp.Options.ScriptDrops = false;
    scrp.Options.WithDependencies = true;
    scrp.Options.Indexes = true;   // To include indexes
    scrp.Options.DriAllConstraints = true;   // to include referential constraints in the script
    scrp.Options.Triggers = true;
    scrp.Options.FullTextIndexes = true;
    scrp.Options.NoCollation = false;
    scrp.Options.Bindings = true;
    scrp.Options.IncludeIfNotExists = false;
    scrp.Options.ScriptBatchTerminator = true;
    scrp.Options.ExtendedProperties = true;

    scrp.PrefetchObjects = true; // some sources suggest this may speed things up

    var urns = new List<Urn>();

    // Iterate through the tables in database and script each one   
    foreach (Table tb in db.Tables)
    {
        // check if the table is not a system table
        if (tb.IsSystemObject == false)
        {
            urns.Add(tb.Urn);
        }
    }

    // Iterate through the views in database and script each one. Display the script.   
    foreach (View view in db.Views)
    {
        // check if the view is not a system object
        if (view.IsSystemObject == false)
        {
            urns.Add(view.Urn);
        }
    }

    // Iterate through the stored procedures in database and script each one. Display the script.   
    foreach (StoredProcedure sp in db.StoredProcedures)
    {
        // check if the procedure is not a system object
        if (sp.IsSystemObject == false)
        {
            urns.Add(sp.Urn);
        }
    }

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection sc = scrp.Script(urns.ToArray());
    foreach (string st in sc)
    {
        // It seems each string is a sensible batch, and putting GO after it makes it work in tools like SSMS.
        // Wrapping each string in an 'exec' statement would work better if using SqlCommand to run the script.
        builder.AppendLine(st);
        builder.AppendLine("GO");
    }

    return builder.ToString();
```

Comment: You can look at the class `Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlScriptPublish.ScriptPublishWizard` from the assembly C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlScriptPublishUI.dll. This is what SSMS uses. (Alternatively, you could look at the class `Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.GenerateScript` from the assembly C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\ReplicationDialog.dll.)

Comment: The example code and links here were a great start, and should be the most complete answer to the OP (which was my exact question as well).

Comment: I hacked together a C# app which allows you to generate SQL server scripts from the command line in Linux. All you need is .Net Core 2 preview: https://github.com/mkurz/SQLServerScripter

Answer (score 23):

I wrote an open source command line utility named [SchemaZen](https://github.com/sethreno/schemazen#schemazen---script-and-create-sql-server-objects-quickly) that does this. It's much faster than scripting from management studio and it's output is more version control friendly. It supports scripting both schema and data.

To generate scripts run:

```
schemazen.exe script --server localhost --database db --scriptDir c:\somedir
```

Then to recreate the database from scripts run:

```
schemazen.exe create --server localhost --database db --scriptDir c:\somedir
```

Comment: I have just tried SchemaZen and I'm really impressed. Worked first time. Thanks Seth!

Comment: @Seth so what are you using to script the objects?  I did not see a single reference to any Microsoft.SqlServer anything (well there was a single unused using statement).

Comment: @John - Schema Zen contains it's own library for scripting. It reads the schema into a model then generates the scripts based on the model. See https://github.com/sethreno/schemazen/blob/master/model/Models/SqlUser.cs for a simple example.

Answer (score 13):

You can use SQL Server Management Object (SMO) to automate SQL Server 2005 management tasks including generating scripts: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162169.aspx.

Answer (score 9):

If you're a developer, definitely go with SMO.  Here's a link to the Scripter class, which is your starting point:

[Scripter Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162153.aspx)

Answer (score 7):

I don't see powershell with SQLPSX mentioned in any of these answers... I personally haven't played with it but it looks beautifully simple to use and ideally suited to this type of automation tasks, with tasks like:

```
Get-SqlDatabase -dbname test -sqlserver server | Get-SqlTable | Get-SqlScripter | Set-Content -Path C:\script.sql
Get-SqlDatabase -dbname test -sqlserver server | Get-SqlStoredProcedure | Get-SqlScripter
Get-SqlDatabase -dbname test -sqlserver server | Get-SqlView | Get-SqlScripter
```

(ref: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1167710-1550-1.aspx#bm1168100)

Project page: http://sqlpsx.codeplex.com/

The main advantage of this approach is that it combines the configurablity / customizability of using SMO directly, with the convenience and maintainability of using a simple existing tool like the Database Publishing Wizard.

Comment: I spent a while trying out this solution, but in the end I turned to C# and using the SMO. The problem I couldn't easily find a way past is that the example code scripts each table individually. Once you start adding in 'DRI' (Declarative Referential Integrity) objects like foreign keys it won't get the dependencies right and/or it will be very slow.

Answer (score 5):

In Tools > Options > Designers > Table and Database Designers there's an option for 'Auto generate change scripts' that will generate one for every change you make at the time you save it.

Comment: That's not exactly what I need. I'd like to get the creation scripts (my final goal is to automatically checkin those files into my source control system)

Answer (score 4):

You can do it with T-SQL code using the INFORMATION_SCHEMA tables.

There are also third-party tools - I like Apex SQL Script for precisely the use you are talking about.  I run it completely from the command-line.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to a Microsoft solution you can try: Microsoft SQL Server Database Publishing Wizard 1.1

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=56E5B1C5-BF17-42E0-A410-371A838E570A&displaylang=en

It create a batch process you can run anytime you need to rebuild the scripts.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't support SqlServer 2008

Comment: Version 1.2 says it supports 2000 and 2005, but I just used it to script a database on 2008 with 3800+ tables and it worked fine. It didn't include compress options, which weren't introduced until 2008. I've also just tested against a 2008 R2 database and it scripts that fine as well.

Answer (score 3):

Try **new SQL Server command line tools to generate T-SQL scripts** and monitor Dynamic Management Views.

Worked for me like charm. It is a new python based tool from Microsoft that runs from command line.
Everything works like described on the Microsoft page (see link below)
Worked for me with SQL 2012 server.

You install it with pip:

> $pip install mssql-scripter

Command parameter overview as usual with h for help:

> mssql-scripter -h

Hint:
If you log in to SQL-Server via Windows authentication, just leave away Username and password.

https://cloudblogs.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2017/05/17/try-new-sql-server-command-line-tools-to-generate-t-sql-scripts-and-monitor-dynamic-management-views/

Answer (score 2):

I've been using DB Comparer - Its free and no fuss script entire DB and can compare to another DB and also produce a Diff script . Excellent for Development to Production change scripts. 
http://www.dbcomparer.com/

Answer (score 1):

From Visual Studio 2008 SP1 TeamSuite :

In the Server Explorer / Data Connections tab, there's a publish to provider tool which does the same as "Microsoft SQL Server Database Publishing Wizard", but which is compatible with MS Sql Server 2008.

Comment: How does it help automating the task?

Answer (score 1):

There is also this simple command line tool I build for my needs.
http://mycodepad.wordpress.com/2013/11/18/export-ms-sql-database-schema-with-c/

It can export an entire db, and it tries to export encrypted objects. Everything is stored in folders and separate sql files for easy file comparison.

Code is also available on github.

Answer (score 0):

I am using VS 2012(for DBs on MSSQL Server 2008) compare database has an option to save it, the comparison and options. This is essentially  what are your settings for delivery. After that you can do update or generate script.

I just find it it a little bit awkward to load it from file later(drag and drop from windows explorer) as I do not see the file in solution explorer.