# Generating the stored procedures from command line

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I want to generate Scripts i.e. Stored procedures and user defined functions from SQL server 2005. I have done it through SQL management studio but i want to to do it through Command line. Is there is any way to do it through command line arguments like sqlcmd.exe or any other scripting.

Comment: Duplicate of [How can I automate the "generate scripts" task in SQL Server Management Studio 2008 ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/483568/how-can-i-automate-the-generate-scripts-task-in-sql-server-management-studio-20) - see this previous SO question for solution on how to do this

Comment: This isn't an exact answer but you may find it a useful alternative: http://weblogs.asp.net/stevewellens/archive/2009/12/11/automatically-generate-stored-procedures-with-visual-studio.aspx

Answer (score 1):

use sp_helptext with a query from SQLCMD
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176112.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer something with a little more flexibility, check out the sys.sql_modules system view, as it gives you a bit extra information about the object and has the nice ability of being able to join to other system tables.

The rest of MauMen's answer is the right direction though: Use SQLCMD to generate the output to a file with the "-o OutputFile.sql".

For example, create a proc:

```
create proc dbo.pr_procDefTest
as
print 'This is a proc definition'
go
```

Show the definition:

```
select m.definition
from sys.procedures p
inner join sys.sql_modules m on p.object_id = m.object_id
where p.name = 'pr_procDefTest'
```

Output with SQLCMD:

```
sqlcmd -E -S .\sqlexpress -d test -o OutputFile.sql -Q "set nocount on; select m.definition from sys.procedures p inner join sys.sql_modules m on p.object_id = m.object_id where p.name = 'pr_procDefTest'" -h -1 -w 65535
```

There are a variety of paramaters passed in, which you can look up on the [sqlcmd Utility MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx). The important thing to note is the use of "set nocount on;" in the beginning of the script to prevent the "(1 rows affected)" footer.

Comment: @Cadeaeic I like your solution.  It expands nicely on what I was thinking.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft released a new tool a few weeks ago called mssql-scripter that's the command line version of the "Generate Scripts" wizard in SSMS. It's a Python-based, open source command line tool and you can find the official announcement [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/dataplatforminsider/2017/05/17/try-new-sql-server-command-line-tools-to-generate-t-sql-scripts-and-monitor-dynamic-management-views/). Essentially, the scripter allows you to generate a T-SQL script for your database/database object as a .sql file. You can generate the file and then execute it. This might be a nice solution for you to generate the schema and/or of your db objects such as stored procs. Here's a quick usage example to get you started:

```
$ pip install mssql-scripter
# script the database schema and data piped to a file.
$ mssql-scripter -S localhost -d AdventureWorks -U sa --include-objects StoredProcs --schema-and-data > ./myFile.sql
```

More usage examples are on our GitHub page here: https://github.com/Microsoft/sql-xplat-cli/blob/dev/doc/usage_guide.md