# How to export SQL Server database structure into text format

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I automate the "generate scripts" task in SQL Server Management Studio 2008?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483568/how-can-i-automate-the-generate-scripts-task-in-sql-server-management-studio-20)

I need to export structure of my SQL Server database into a .sql script(s) without management studio.

**UPDATED**

Comment: You could use a third-party tool like [ApexSQL SQL Script](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_script.aspx) to achieve this... `bcp` is really more for the **data** import/export (rather than the database's structure)

Answer (score 15):

In `SQL Management Studio`:

- Right click on Database entry
- In menu select `Task -> Generate Scripts`
- Specify what exacly you want to generate (schema only, +functions, +stored procedures,..)

Comment: I want to automize this task, so this approach is not acceptable for me

Comment: So you need to export only schema?

Answer (score 4):

Try out `Tasks -> Generate scripts` menu in SQL Management Studio