# copy database structure from sql server to other

Tags: sql-server

I want to copy a database to a sql server to another, but i just want to copy structure (views, stored procedures, tables, fields, indexes, etc), no rows.
I tried to generate a script from sql server management but the script is very verbose (task menu > create as)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to copy schema and some data from SQL Server to another instance?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7245793/how-to-copy-schema-and-some-data-from-sql-server-to-another-instance)

Comment: Try with SSIS task transfer SQL Server Objects Task:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142159(v=sql.120).aspx

Comment: As Chetan suggested, [SQL Server Script Wizard](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/sql-server-script-database-by-sql-2008-script-wizard.aspx) is one of the most handy tools for creating scripts of database objects
You can even script data in the selected database tables.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Follow Below steps for generate script :

- Right Click on Database
- Select task
- Select Generate Script from Task
- Follow the steps
- Finally finish for complete this process

  You can either use the [SQL Server Management Object API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162169.aspx) (see task ["creating, altering and removing databases"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162577.aspx)):

C# Code for generate sql script :

```
public string GenerateScript()
{
      var sb = new StringBuilder();

      var srv= new Server(@"Your Database Server Name");
      var db= server.Databases["Your Database name"];

      var scrpt = new Scripter(srv);
      scrpt.Options.ScriptDrops = false;

      var obj= new Urn[1];
      foreach (Table tbl in db.Tables)
      {
          obj[0] = tbl.Urn;
          if (tbl.IsSystemObject == false)
          {
              StringCollection sc = scripter.Script(obj);

              foreach (var st in sc)
              {
                  sb.Append(st);
              }
           }
       }
            return sb.ToString();
 }
```

Comment: Is there a way to generate this via a SQL Command instead of using sql server management studio ?

Comment: @Bob5421 : I have edited my answer and write code for generate script

Comment: This give me a lot of sql commands like SET ANSI_NULLS ON, SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON, WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON  . Is there a way to only get CREATE TABLE, indexes and primary key, without those options ? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You case use [Copy database wizard](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188664.aspx)

Some limitations of the it are :

1.The Copy Database Wizard is not available in the Express edition.

1.The Copy Database Wizard cannot be used to copy or move databases that:
Are System.
Are marked for replication.
Are marked Inaccessible, Loading, Offline, Recovering, Suspect, or in Emergency Mode.
Have data or log files stored in Microsoft Azure storage.

Comment: This is the same thing than in task submenu. It produces something very verbose