# How to copy complete schema to a new schema

Tags: sql-server, database-schema, saas

I'm working on a saas application which has an sql server database.  I have tables, functions, and stored procedures in a particular schema (i.e. customer1.table1, customer1.spGetCustomers, etc.).  I would like a way of copying the entire schema tables, functions, stored procedures, indexes, keys, etc. to a new empty schema for each new customer.  I was hoping there was an fast easy way to do this so that I can add new schemas for every new customer and keep everything completely separate.  I don't want a new database for each customer because of the cost and extra maintenance.

Please help.

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem, in my opinion. Have you, however, considered using the Generate Scripts functionality of SSMS, or simply using a Find and Replace against your Source Control Scripts?

Comment: By using a multi-tenant database architecture with each tenant having their own schema you have the worst of both worlds. Now all customers share a single database but each has their own set of objects. So you lose the ability to restore single customers and keep the challenge of requiring updates to a huge list of identical objects. Essentially what you are describing is that you have chosen the path that provides you the downside of separate databases and the downside of sharing a database.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to copy schema and some data from SQL Server to another instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7245793/how-to-copy-schema-and-some-data-from-sql-server-to-another-instance)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use SQLCMD variables in create scripts.
You will write schema independent create object scripts, something like:

```
CREATE TABLE [$(schema)].Table1 ...
CREATE PROCEDURE [$(schema)].Proc1...
```

Then you will execute it as:

```
sqlcmd -v schema ="Customer1" -i c:\script.sql
```