# Batch extract of SQL Server DDL

Tags: sql-server, batch-file, ddl

Since we can point and click in SSMS to obtain DDL, there must be an assembly or DLL of some sort called by the GUI.  Does anyone have any familiarity with how to tap into that?

The drive for this comes from our need to capture DDL as part of jobs.  Some of our batches only need the data for one table or even one index, others could use the entire database.  Getting the detail as needed is critical.  That detail might be used as part of a procedure or placed into a file.

I know there are various solutions to the problem of batch/automated retrieval of SQL Server DDL (versions 2000-2014) on the web.  None are directly supported by Microsoft, and for what I need, that is a considerable weakness.

Of the items on the web, some use scripts and the system views/tables to build DDL.  I admire the work that went into these, but such things may have problematic support and can break from SQL Server version to SQL Server version.  Also, a number of vendors have tools, and there is at least one open source project (OpenDiff) that ventures into this area.  But vendor tools won't easily fit into my batch streams.  And third party tools also require installation on client systems, which is always a sensitive area, and usually have licensing requirements.  Any third party tool, of course, introduces the various types of vendor dependencies.

There is one item I have found, SMOScript, that uses SMOs (with which I am only slightly familiar).  Perhaps that is doing something similar to what I want, though the limited notes on the project imply that it does not allow the detail needed such as for a single index.  From a management viewpoint, it also introduces a dependency on that project and its single author.

That assembly used by SSMS, whatever it is, must be kept up to date by MS.  If calling that is possible (though I am sure it is foolish to hope it is also simple), the weakness of a third party dependency is eliminated.  So I don't need web links to scripts and third party tools for those I have (yet thanks for the thought), but if someone can point me toward what SSMS is using, that might be a great help.  In the meantime, for what its worth, I'll be researching SMOs.

Comment: I suggest you look at SMO more closely.  It has a object model that allows to script and manage much of SQL Server, and is fully supported by Microsoft.

Comment: Did you see this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/483568 - specifically the second answer and the comment on it.