# View the source for an sql server agent job?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-agent

In SQL Management Studio, you can right click on an Agent Job and choose 'Script Job as' -> 'Create to/Drop to', which will reveal the backend code for the agent job.

Is there a script I can execute which would generate this code as well?

I've been searching for details on this, but all I can find so far is references for viewing the script via SQL Management Studio ([Example 1](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/fdfc00d7-ea7b-4484-84d3-fa25f7b82b65/how-to-script-all-sql-jobs), [Example 2](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191450(v=sql.105).aspx), [Example 3](https://www.toadworld.com/platforms/sql-server/b/weblog/archive/2013/03/18/how-to-create-scripts-for-all-selected-sql-server-agent-jobs)).

If anyone could point me in the proper direction containing ANY details on how to query for a creation script, that would be awesome.

Comment: Check this SO question, it points out the VS command line util that will generate the code.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/483568/how-can-i-automate-the-generate-scripts-task-in-sql-server-management-studio-2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running a Profiler Trace while running the 'Script Job as' -> 'Create to' reveals a set of SQL statements that you could mimic:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't though to use a Profiler trace. For some reason I was thinking that because it was via an SQL Agent, the trace may not see it. I'll give that a go though.