# Execute more than one query on SQL SERVER 2014

Tags: t-sql, ssms, sql-server-2014

my program has to accomplish these tasks:

1. Connect to a remote SQLServer database.
2. Getting data of each table in the database, and each column of each table.
3. With the data obtained write queries to create a copy of the database

Everything goes fine, but when i try to run the query on my DBMS (Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio)
it returns errors with the last entry but everything goes fine if i run one single query. What am i doing wrong? Here's is a snippet of the result

```
IF NOT EXISTS (select * from dbo.sysobjects where id = object_id(N'[test]') and OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsUserTable') = 1) 
BEGIN 
CREATE TABLE dbo.test(
  KeyId numeric(18, 0) PRIMARY KEY  NOT NULL,
  intNumTest numeric(18, 0)  NULL,
  intNumTest2 numeric(18, 0)  NULL);
END
```

Imagine there are hundred of these kind of query, every single one running fine but returning errors if ran together

Comment: what you are looking for is generate scripts :look out here for more info:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/483568/how-can-i-automate-the-generate-scripts-task-in-sql-server-management-studio-2

Comment: What's the error message? Consider updating the question with the smallest possible example you can come up with that generates the error.

Comment: solved by creating scripts instead of queries